# How to set tags in horizontal line in a v-for using Laravel - Vue.js and Element-ui

Tags: laravel, vue.js, element-ui

I'm trying to show categories of a recipe with `<el-tag>`, however they're all showing like one under the other: 
[image]

I would like them to be more like this

[image]

These tags are inside an `<el-table>` which has this stucture

```
<el-table>
    <el-table-column
        prop="name"
        label="Name">
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column
        label="Category">
        <template slot-scope="scope">
            <div class="tag-container" v-for="cat in scope.row.categories">
                <el-tag type="success">{{cat.name}}</el-tag>
            </div>
        </template>
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column
        align="right">
        <template slot="header" slot-scope="scope">
            <el-input
                v-model="search"
                size="medium"
                placeholder="Search"/>
        </template>

        <template slot-scope="scope">
            <div class="btn-link-edit action-button" @click="edit(scope.row)">
                <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-link-delete action-button" @click="remove(scope.row)">
                <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
            </div>
        </template>
    </el-table-column>
</el-table>
```

I also creating the class

```
.tag-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

Is there a way to make them look like the example I showed?

Comment: use [flex box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: @MikeRoss these are inside a table row, can this still be used in there?

Comment: add some more code or fiddle so we can help more.

Comment: @MikeRoss I've added the table structure

Comment: I'm using the Element-ui table component https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following css class

```
.container {
  display: flex; /* or inline-flex */
  flex-direction: row
}
```

Turns out you don't need flex

checkout [this codepen](https://codepen.io/bhavuksuthar/pen/XWWqLXo)

```
<el-table-column
    label="Category">
    <template slot-scope="scope">
        <template v-for="cat in scope.row.categories">
            <el-tag type="success">{{cat.name}}</el-tag>
        </div>
    </template>
</el-table-column>
```

Comment: I ended up wrapping the div with another div and setting this class to that and adding a margin-right to the tag class, and this gave me result I wanted, Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm pretty late to answer this but I just had this issue myself and discovered that the issue was that you're using `v-for` on the container element. That is why your code was creating multiple containers with the child inside but really you only wanted to create multiple children within that one single container. Also, it would be a good idea to always add the `key` attribute on the same line you're using `v-for` for Vue.js

**Your code**

```
<div class="tag-container" v-for="cat in scope.row.categories">
    <el-tag type="success">{{cat.name}}</el-tag>
</div>
```

**Code that would fix your issue**

```
<div class="tag-container">
    <el-tag type="success" v-for="cat in scope.row.categories">{{cat.name}}</el-tag>
</div>
```